# How to Get Service Fabric Project Settings.xml Values

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have 5 service fabric stateless services. I have to get these service fabric settings.xml values in a class library based on Section Name of each file. I am going to create a common class which will take SectionName as a parameter and have to get all configuration values.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as a starting point:

```
internal sealed class YourService: StatelessService
{
    public YourService(StatelessServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        var configurationPackage = Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
        var sectionParams = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["sectionname"].Parameters;
        // You can now iterate through these parameters (e.g. get count and access by index)
        //sectionParams.Count;
        //sectionParams[0].Name;
        //sectionParams[0].Value;
```

I am not sure if there is a way for a library to find the ServiceContext of other Services. Please also be aware that not all services might be deployed to the same nodes. This might affect configuration availability.

You might need to create a central service or actor that collects the configuration values of all other services.